# Alloy compiler failed but classic Titanium works

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

when I try to run a basic alloy app (two-tabbed template) I get this error:

```
[ERROR] :  : Cannot find module './validators/react/isReactComponent'
[ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

But when I run a classic app (two-tabbed template) whithout alloy then program runs ok.

My system is:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.14.5
  Architecture                = 64bit

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 8.9.1
  npm Version                 = 5.5.1

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.15
  Core Package                = 7.1.2

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.2.2
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.49
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update your Node version to 10.x (e.g. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/). After that install the CLI again (`npm install -g appcelerator titanium alloy`) and run `appc use 7.1.2 --force` to be sure that all packages are rebuild and you should be able to run the app